# Looking for File Copy function in C#

Tags: c#

I'm writing a tool that performs copying from USB devices to the local HD - I wonder if there is a function in C# to copy a file from one path to another?

Comment: @Shira: You may want to work on your title writing skills.  Try to have a title that wouldn't fit 10,000 other questions equally well.  In this case, something like "Is there a function in C# to copy from USB to the local HDD?" would be a huge improvement.

Comment: @Rohan: Really?  You took the time to edit the title, and it's still possibly the worst title on SO?  (Ok, I admit it's better than "help me")

Comment: Ben Voigt: someone answered me despite my bad writing skills- but still thank you- i'll work on it

Comment: @Ben, I just corrected the spelling mistake :)

Comment: A good example of [C# File.Copy](https://www.dotnetperls.com/file-copy).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes! The cunningly named:

[File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: arh, c'mon... thats too easy :P

Comment: there's plenty more where that came from - ask me how to delete a file... go on... ask me....

Comment: even though it's easy- i got the fast answer than any kind of search, do u have any problem with it?

Answer (score 4):

`File.Copy` is probably OK for what you want to do, but it doesn't provide much flexibility (no cancellation, no progress tracking...).

If you need those features, you can look at the [`CopyFileEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363852.aspx) API, which supports them. I wrote a .NET wrapper for `CopyFileEx` (and also `MoveFileWithProgress`), you can find it [here](http://projets.developpez.com/projects/dvp-net/repository/entry/trunk/src/Developpez.Dotnet.System/FileCopyOperation.cs) (documentation comments are in French, sorry about that... hopefully that won't be an issue). Here's how you can use it:

```
void CopyFile(string source, string destination)
{
    var copy = new FileCopyOperation(source, destination);
    copy.ReplaceExisting = true;
    copy.ProgressChanged += copy_ProgressChanged;

    copy.Execute();
}

void copy_ProgressChanged(object sender, FileOperationProgressEventArgs e)
{
    copyProgressBar.Value = e.PercentDone;

    if (abortRequested)
        e.Action = FileOperationProgressAction.Cancel;
}
```

Comment: Never document any code in a language other than English if you intend to publish it. In fact, think about what happens when you don't comment in English on a closed-source project and you have to co-operate with a non-french speaking programmer.

Comment: @the_drow: I would usually agree with you, but this project is developed with other members of a French developer community, and is primarily intended for this community, so it makes sense to write the documentation in French. Perhaps someday we'll want to reach a larger audience, and we'll translate the documentation...